# Limit at boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n_+$ be an open cone with positive points and $f\colon X \rightarrow [0,1]^n$ be a continuous function. I want to ensure that as $\delta > 0$ tends to zero $f(\delta x)$ tends to the same limit point independent of $x$. I can do this by assuming uniform continuity of $f$. But I know that $f$ is monotone in the following sense: for every $x$, $y \in X$, $(x-y) \cdot (f(x) -f(y)) \ge 0$. Does monotonicity imply that continuity itself guarantees me the limit to exist at origin? It is clearly true for $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, monotonicity of $f$ does not give the desired conclusion when $n\ge 2$. Consider $f(x)=x/|x|$ where $|\cdot |$ is the Euclidean norm of $x$. This function is continuous on $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$, and it is is monotone. But the limit of $f(\delta x)$ as $\delta\to 0$ is $x/|x|$.

The monotonicity of $f$ can be checked directly, but it is easier to observe that $f$ is the gradient of convex function $u(x)=|x|$, and use the well-known fact that the gradient of a convex function is monotone (which follows directly from the fact that the graph of $u$ lies above its tangent plane).